# reactjs mobx without decorators not working

Tags: reactjs, decorator, mobx, create-react-app, mobx-react

I am trying to incorporate `mobx` with `react`. Since I spawned my application using `create-react-app`, I can't use decorators given by mobx.

Given that we can use mobx without decorators as per this documentation: https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/decorators.html

Here's a component that I created:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import observer from 'mobx-react';

export const TestComponent = observer(class TestComponent extends Component {

  render() {
     return <div>Just a test component!</div>
  }

});
```

Here's a simple calling of the above component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

import Auth from './Auth'
import { TestComponent } from './Test'

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import  authStore  from './stores/Store'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <TestComponent store={authStore} />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now when I run the above component, I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _mobxReact2.default) is not a function(…)` nothing get displays in console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `import {observer} from 'mobx-react';`

N.B. note that decorators can be used with create-react-app by using [custom-react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-react-scripts), as explained [here](https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a#.n6xx12p5c))

Comment: Thank you. I had missed this basic thing.

On a side note, can I use custom-react-scripts with my already working project? I don't want to create a new one.

Comment: afaik yes that is possible

Comment: Best ask the author of the above blog, but I would expect npm installing the package and creating the config file should do the trick?